# How does calling java Thread join() method makes the outer thread to wait while it should have been the thread itself which called join()?

Tags: java, multithreading

The java code for join() method is below

```
public final synchronized void join(long millis)
    throws InterruptedException {
        long base = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long now = 0;

        if (millis < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout value is negative");
        }

        if (millis == 0) {
            while (isAlive()) {
                wait(0);
            }
        } else {
            while (isAlive()) {
                long delay = millis - now;
                if (delay <= 0) {
                    break;
                }
                wait(delay);
                now = System.currentTimeMillis() - base;
            }
        }
    }
```

So according to this whenever we call someThreadobj.join() this thread obtains a lock and goes in wating. Then how come when i call it from main thread makes the main thread to wait.

This is what I am testing with

```
public class Test {

  volatile int i = 10;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Test obj = new Test();

    Thread th1 = new Thread(() -> {
      for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(2000);
          System.out.println("Inside Thread ... " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }
    });

    Thread th2 = new Thread(() -> {
      for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(2000);
          System.out.println("Inside Thread ... " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });

    Thread th3 = new Thread(() -> {
      for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(2000);
          System.out.println("Inside Thread ... " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });

    th1.start();
    th1.join();
    th2.start();
    th2.join();
    th3.start();
  }
}

Output 
Inside Thread ... Thread-0
Inside Thread ... Thread-0
Inside Thread ... Thread-0
Inside Thread ... Thread-0
Inside Thread ... Thread-1
Inside Thread ... Thread-1
Inside Thread ... Thread-1
Inside Thread ... Thread-1
Inside Thread ... Thread-1
Inside Thread ... Thread-2
Inside Thread ... Thread-2
Inside Thread ... Thread-2
Inside Thread ... Thread-2
Inside Thread ... Thread-2
```

Shouldn't the main thread would have started all the thread at once.

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't the main thread would have started all the thread at once.

No, because you didn't start the subsequent threads until the earlier ones completed, because you used `join` between the calls to `start`, and the `join` makes the main thread wait until the one you called `join` on is done. The thread constructor just creates the thread object, it doesn't start the thread.

If you want all the threads started at once, call `start` without calling `join` in-between.

```
th1.start();
th2.start();
th3.start();
th1.join();
th2.join();
th3.join(); // (This one was missing)
```

Comment: thanks for a quick reply, but doesn't call to th1.join() will make th1 thread to wait,  how it is making the main thread to wait thats my thought

Comment: @GautamNaik - When you call `join` on thread `th1`, the thread the call is being made on is what waits, not thread `th1`. `th1.join()` means "make the current thread wait until thread `th1` completes," not `make `th1` wait." See: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#join()

Comment: I got that but looking into the source code as i have attached above join() method is internally calling wait() which according to me will send the calling thread which has acquired lock in WAITING state. And in the above code lock on Test class object is acquired by thread th1 first not the main thread.

Comment: @GautamNaik - Right, the **calling** thread waits, not the thread that `wait` is called on.

Comment: ohh ok now I got it, thanks a lot for bearing with me in this.

Answer (score 0):

> So according to this whenever we call someThreadobj.join() this thread
>   obtains a lock and goes in wating. Then how come when i call it from
>   main thread makes the main thread to wait.

If you see the code of `Thread.join()` you would see that the lock is held on the thread reference which called the `join()` method. So when you call the `join()` on the thread instance the main thread acquires a lock on that thread object (`th1`) and checks whether the thread is still running or not using the `isAlive()` method:

```
while (isAlive()) {
  long delay = millis - now;
  if (delay <= 0) {
      break;
  }
  wait(delay);
  now = System.currentTimeMillis() - base;
}
```

you see clearly that the `wait()` is called on the thread instance, that is the after acquiring the lock the main thread goes into a waiting state and waits for a certain duration provided by the `delay` which is calculated periodically.

Now when the other thread is completed it will issue a `notifyAll()` call so othet threads waiting (main thread) will be woken up and execute.